# How to automatically activate a predefined page in flexdashboard Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have the following Rmarkdown code using **[flexdashboard](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#multiple_pages)**.

````
---
title: "Multiple Pages"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Page 1
===================================== 

### Chart 1

```{r}
```


Page 2
=====================================     

### Chart 1

```{r}
```

Page 3
=====================================     

### Chart 1

```{r}
```
````

It produces the following HTML:

[image]

As stated in above, how can I modify Rmarkdown code so that it automatically go to Page3 active upon loading the page.

Comment: Page 3 {.active}   should work I think